# Problemas con css y js de Select2 en laravel

Tags: laravel, select2

Estoy utilizando laravel con una plantilla AdminLte que supuesta mente trae el css y js de Select2, paquete que necesito para tener multiselects, pero no funciona simplemete me pone el multiselect de html plano. que puede estar pasando, estoy utilizando este codigo:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="permissions" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($permission as $per)
      <option value="{{$per->id}}" >{{$per->display_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código relacionado, sin código no podemos ayudar.

Comment: Le colocaste la funcion .select2 al id o a la clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente a pesar de que esten los archivos css y js en la plantilla tienes que asignarlos a los elementos que necesites por ejemplo:

```
 <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="permissions" multiple="multiple">
   @foreach($permission as $per)
    <option value="{{$per->id}}" >{{$per->display_name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>

    //Al final de tu html o en tu archivo js relacionado
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        });
       </script>
```

Luego sino funciona verifica en los errores de la consola javascript para ver si te pide los archivos js o css.

Comment: No tiene sentido agregar una respuesta sin tener algo de código por parte del OP, es como disparar al aire. -1

Comment: Pero el script ese lo pongo al final del html???

Comment: Si puedes ponerlo al final del html, claro verificando que tienes jquery importado, de todas formas la consola te mostrara en el error el archivo que te falte

Comment: Ya funciono gracias a todos sigan asi

Comment: me pueden decir si estos selects mandan los datos en el request en forma de areglo???

Comment: Tienes que agregarle corchetes al nombre del select asi: name="permissions[]" puedes ver un ejemplo de implementacion mas detallado en este enlace: https://styde.net/etiquetas-dinamicas-con-select2-y-ajax-en-laravel/